# Flutter GectureDetector onTap works only on text child

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gesturedetector

I try to create an app which changes the background color to a random color when user taps anywhere on the screen but OnTap function works only when I tap on the text. Please help me how can I fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainVidget();
  }
}

class MainVidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainVidgetState createState() => MainVidgetState();
}

class MainVidgetState extends State<MainVidget> {
  Color mainColor = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: mainColor,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Tap anywhere'),
          ),
          body: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                mainColor = Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(254) + 1,
                    Random().nextInt(254) + 1, Random().nextInt(254) + 1, 1);
              });
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Text('Hey there', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to achieve this is to use a `Stack` with the top-level page being a `Listener` with a behavior property `HittestBehavior.translucent`.

```dart
body: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Center(
      child: Text('Hey there', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
    ),
    Listener(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onPointerDown: (e) {
        setState(() {
          mainColor = Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(254) + 1,
              Random().nextInt(254) + 1, Random().nextInt(254) + 1, 1);
        });
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```

Now on why this method is a slightly safer approach:

- This will not obstruct any other `GestureDetector` with the same callback.

But if you are using a `GestureDetector` instead of `Listener` for eg. If you end up using a `Stack` or have a `GestureDetector` as a child inside a `GestureDetector` with same callbacks like `onTap` and `onTap` or `onLongPress` and `onLongPress` etc.. then only one of the `GestureDetector`s would fire.

The reason for that being `GestureDetector`s will participate in a Gesture arena and compete for gestures then finally only one of them will win.

But a `Listener` would not participate in a gesture arena thus it will receive events no matter what.

The disadvantage being a `Listener` can receive raw pointer events unlike a `GestureDetector` which is more sophisticated.

A slightly more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45253#issuecomment-564093260)

Answer (score 12):

Set `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` in `GestureDetector`.

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, //or HitTestBehavior.opaque
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      mainColor = Color.fromRGBO(Random().nextInt(254) + 1,
          Random().nextInt(254) + 1, Random().nextInt(254) + 1, 1);
    });
  },
  child: Center(
    child: Text('Hey there', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0)),
  ),
),
```